# Is there a straightforward way to remove existing FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND from @Lexical/react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lexicaljs

I thought there would be a plugin for this, but I can't find one anywhere. I would like to register a command that removes any 'bold', 'italic', or 'underline' from a selection when a clear formatting icon button is clicked.

I have tried registering my own command like this:

```
const CLEAR_FORMAT_COMMAND: LexicalCommand<void> = createCommand();
```

and then in a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return mergeRegister(
      editor.registerUpdateListener(({ editorState }) => {
        editorState.read(() => {
          updateToolbar();
        })
      }),
      editor.registerCommand(
        CLEAR_FORMAT_COMMAND,
        () => {
          clearFormat(editor);
          return true;
        },
        COMMAND_PRIORITY_LOW,
      )
    );
  }, [updateToolbar, editor]);
```

and then `onClick` of the clear formatting icon, these get called:

```
editor.dispatchCommand(CLEAR_FORMAT_COMMAND, undefined) 
editor.dispatchCommand(REMOVE_LIST_COMMAND, undefined)
setBlockType('paragraph')
```

The `REMOVE_LIST_COMMAND` works as expected. For some reason, the custom one does not, and `clearFormat` function in the register command never gets fired. And if it did, I'm not sure what to do inside it. I was thinking something like this, but I have not been able to get the `dispatchCommand` working in order to test it:

```
const clearFormat = (editor:LexicalEditor) => {
  editor.update(() => {
      const selection = $getSelection();
      if (selection.hasFormat('bold')) {
        selection.toggleFormat('bold');
      }
      ...
    })
}
```

Comment: There was an example for having clear format in the toolbar in the old playground, maybe it can help: https://github.com/facebook/lexical/pull/2295/files#diff-57c77f91d65c3b3be92d7dc10d39982bf59cc9deac7bf7d64fec1260ff19ecf3

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me with lexical 0.11.1:

```
editor.update(() => {
  const selection = $getSelection();
  if ($isRangeSelection(selection)) {
    selection.getNodes().forEach((node) => {
      if ($isTextNode(node)) {
        node.setFormat(0);
        node.setStyle("");
      } else if ($isLinkNode(node)) {
        const children = node.getChildren();
        for (const child of children) {
          node.insertBefore(child);
        }
        node.remove();
      }
    });
    $setBlocksType(selection, () => $createParagraphNode());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is still in the playground, nested in a dropdown. It's the `clearFormatting` [function here](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/blob/f3d26bf4a50db2a0e1db965d5ba8c8ce4a705cf8/packages/lexical-playground/src/plugins/ToolbarPlugin/index.tsx#L577C2-L577C46). My implementation is simpler, so I just used:

```
const clearFormat = useCallback(() => {
  editor.update(() => {
    const selection = $getSelection();
    if ($isRangeSelection(selection)) {
      selection.getNodes().forEach((node) => {
        if ($isTextNode(node)) {
          node.setFormat(0);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}, [editor]);
```